# Panic While importing Downloaded packages in GOLang

Tags: go

I have installed the latest GoLang version (1.6.4) recently in Windows 10 AMD64, I installed same packages with **go get** command, every time i tried to import the package i got this error

> tl.go:18:3: no required module provides package fyne.io/fyne/v2: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'

It work well with Golang version 1.15

Comment: 1.6.4 is not the latest go version -- typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Module-aware mode is enabled by default, regardless of whether a `go.mod` file is present in the current working directory or a parent directory. More precisely, the `GO111MODULE` environment variable now defaults to on. To switch to the previous behavior, set `GO111MODULE` to `auto`."

https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command

So, Go is assuming module mode by default (and thus expecting a mod file), whereas before it was context-dependent, defaulting to using Go workspaces in your case.